# javascript function return value for html form validation

Tags: javascript

Below is my javascript code.

I am validating form data for that I am using in the if conditions.

If it gets validated properly then hide all warnings and if not show only warnings of that field and return false. But that function is  not returning false.

Code:

```
 function check_form()
 {
 var name=document.signin_form.full_name.value;
 var userid=document.signin_form.userid.value;
 var gender=document.signin_form.gender.value;
 var dob=document.signin_form.dob.value;
 var add=document.signin_form.address.value;
 var pass=document.signin_form.pass.value;
 var tc=document.signin_form.tc.checked;

if(name!==""&&name.length<30&&name.match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/))
{
right();
}
else
{
 wrong("name");
 return false;
}

}
function right()
{
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#name_warning").css("display","none");
$("#userid_warning").css("display","none");
$("#gender_warning").css("display","none");
$("#dob_warning").css("display","none");
$("#address_warning").css("display","none");
$("#password_warning").css("display","none");
$("#tc_warning").css("display","none");
});

}
function wrong(str)
{
str="'#"+str+"_warning'";
$(document).ready(function(){
$(str).css("display","inline-block");
});
window.scroll(0,250); 
}
```

Comment: Have you got any sample input?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Can you please provide the snippet of HTML as well? It is difficult to understand if it is fetching exact value or not and how it is submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't return `true` if the validation was ok(where you call `right()`. So if you are capturing the return value of the function , you will get `undefined`, which is treated the same as `false`(see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Try returning `true` after calling `right()`.

You can see in this example that even though the validation passed, `s is not ok` is still printed, for this reason.

```js
var s = "abcdef";
var validate = function(name){
  if(name!==""&&name.length<30&&name.match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/)){
    console.log("right");
  }else{
    console.log("wrong");
    return false;
  }
};

if(validate(s)){
  console.log("s was ok");
}else{
  console.log("s was not ok");
}
```

But if you return `true`, things work as expected:

```js
var s = "abcdef";
var validate = function(name){
  if(name!==""&&name.length<30&&name.match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/)){
    console.log("right");
    return true;
  }else{
    console.log("wrong");
    return false;
  }
};

if(validate(s)){
  console.log("s was ok");
}else{
  console.log("s was not ok");
}
```

Comment: i added return ture below right function ,but not working.

Comment: Then edit the question and provide more information. What is `check_form` actually returning? What is the value of `name`? Use the debugger if needed.

Comment: it's very simple.  **check_form**  will execute when form will submit and will  return a value. **name** is a input feild value where user enter his full name.

Comment: Yes. I understand that. What is the actual *runtime* values of `name` that are causing the trouble? For all we know the user is inputting more than 30 characters, or numbers, so `check_form` *should* fail. In your question you say "but that function is not returning false" - so what is it returning?

Comment: i have checked return value using another function, it is returning properly that if validation fails it returns false and if validation goes properly it returns ture. but form is  submitting on both value.  why?

Comment: You don't show the code where you are using `check_form`, so it is impossible for us to say.